# Change "Public file system path" with Amazon S3

Tags: files

I want to keep my media files, all files in the "default/files" folder in the Amazon S3 account. I've opened the "admin/config/media/file-system" page and there is the "Public file system path" field, which by default is set to sites/default/files.

I can't imagine how can I connect my Amazon account with this file system path.

I'm using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the following module: [AmazonS3](http://drupal.org/project/AmazonS3).

Comment: thanks, i've found this module, but i cant't replace it with Drupal's own file system, I couldn't find that part

Comment: You don't replace, it provides an additional file system next to public/private and you can either set that as the default or configure each field separately if you want to use amazon or the local public file system.

Comment: i'm at admin/config/media/file-system in my site and i can see only Public file system path, Private file system path and  Temporary directory fields, and I've no option to choose or change it into Amazon S3

Answer (score 2):

Once you've configured your bucket, I believe you need to configure the public path to be something like:

```
s3://public/path
```

as opposed to

```
sites/default/files
```